# Getting img.src value (path name)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form for a registration page. The form contains an image that changes its src dependant on a situation. 
Within a script which activates upon submission of the form, I want the form to call an alert if that image has a particular src, so I need a way of retrieving and comparing the value.

HTML:

```
<form action="register_submit.php" method="post" name="mainform" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return checkForm(this);return false;">
```

JS:

```
    function checkForm(f)
    {if ([image src value] == "pictures/apic.png")
       {
          alert("error picture is apic");
          return false;
       }
     else
       {
          f.submit();
          return false;
       }
    }
```

Here is the relative code in full:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function checkForm(f)
            {if ([image src value] == "pictures/apic.png")
               {
                  alert("error picture is apic");
                  return false;
               }
             else
               {
                  f.submit();
                  return false;
               }
            }
    </script>

    <form action="register_submit.php" method="post" name="mainform" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return checkForm(this);return false;">

    <div class="required">
    <label for="first_name">*First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="inputText" onkeyup="checkFName(this.value);" onblur="checkFName(this.value);" maxlength="20" size="10" value="" />
    <img id="FName_Status" name="FName_Status" src="/pictures/bad.png" style="margin-left:5px; position:absolute;" alt="FName_Status" />
    </div>

    (OTHER OBJECTS)
    </form>

<input type="submit"  name="sub" class="inputSubmit" value="Submit &raquo;"/>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this:

```
if (document.getElementById('FName_Status').getAttribute('src') == "pictures/apic.png")
```

Comment: where do I specify the img element, as there are many on the page. For example if <img id="foo"...

Comment: `f.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]` refers to the first image element inside your `f` form

Comment: is there any way to state a range (e.g. all elements) or do this by image id/name instead.

Comment: you can use a for statement to test all `document.getElementsByTagName('img')` items

Comment: I cannot seem to get your code to work, I have edited the post to show all the relative code, can you see what the problem is?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the main issue here is that the submit button is outside the form tag...

Comment: sorry I pasted the code incorrectly, on my document it is actually inside the form.

Answer (score 1):

Add an ID tag to your image (if it doesn't already have one), eg:

```
<img src="pictures/apic.png" id="imageId" />
```

Then you can reference it as follows:

```
if (document.getElementById("imageId").src == "pictures/apic.png")
{
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/2Wtkn/2/

Comment: Here's a very simple fiddle demonstrating it working: http://jsfiddle.net/2Wtkn/.  Perhaps if you post your entire code we can see what exactly is wrong.

Comment: There main problem with your code is that the submit button is outside the `<form>` tag, so your `checkForm()` function never runs.  Another thing to note is that your `checkForm()` function does not need to call the form's `submit()` method directly - you just need to return `true` to allow the submission to continue, or `false` to cancel it.  Here is an updated fiddle that works correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/2Wtkn/2/

Comment: Your code does not work unless I change .src to .getAttribute('src').
I have used your improved function however :)